# Where gnome apps are installed?

Tags: gnome

I would like to know where the gnome apps are installed. Are they compiled and only exist in the binary form in `usr/bin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnome applications are installed like any other software package on your Linux distribution.

Applications written using a compiled language are in a binary form. Those written in an interpreted language are not.

Concerning the installation location, it depends on the package provided by your Linux distribution. `/usr/bin` is the usual location of the executable while `/usr/lib` contains the program libraries and `/usr/share` the assets.

Comment: That didn't answer my question...

Comment: I edited my answer trying to better answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcuts of applications are stored you can go to

```
/usr/share/applications/
/usr/local/share/applications.
~/.local/share/applications/
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/
```

These places have a *.desktop* file in which all the asset details are stored including which file to execute when opening these shortcuts. You can also edit these desktop files and add one of your own

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to find an application (but when right-clicking and choosing "Show Details", Snap manager in Ubuntu would show nothing). A simple search of those directories helped.